Bad Gateway azure, application gateway
i am having trouble with bad gateway 502, these are the errors
this is my inbound settingsthis is my outbound settingsand this is my application gateway can somebody help me? I can pass more info if needed!
i noticed the certificate error but i couldnt check for the CN since i cant log into the machine (i dont know how) im completely lost now


Bad Gateway azure, application gateway due to certificate expiry and CN mismatch.

In general, 502 gateway issue occurs when the certificate expiry happens or CN name of certificate mismatches.
The FQDN of the backend pool target doesn’t match the Common Name (CN) of the backend server’s certificate or it might expire.
Refer to this Microsoftdoc to get connected with the machine and access the certificate and update it accordingly as per the requirement and the Microsoftdoc to get the clarity of this issue of updating the certificate as per the requriement.
If you have no  HTTPS Only  on, this issue may happen due to the following main reasons:

You have redirection configured on your App Service. Redirection can be as simple as adding a trailing slash to the request.
You have Azure AD authentication which causes the redirection.
You have enabled “Pick Host Name from Backend Address” switch in the HTTP settings of Application Gateway.
You don’t have your custom domain registered with your App Service.

Refer:
Application Gateway 502 error when configuring it for Azure Web App - Stack Overflow by Nancy Xiong
Azure Application Gateway: 502 error due to backend certificate not whitelisted in the AppGW - Microsoft Community Hub by Shaik Athahar Nawaz (SAN)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#common-name-cn-doesnt-match
